# Consulta con muchos campos y registros en MySQL

Tags: mysql, jquery, select

Muy buenas tardes foro de **STACKOVERFLOW**, espero puedan apoyarme con una consulta de MySQL

Tengo una tabla de 72 columnas y 64 registros. La tabla así la requiere mi jefe por cuestiones de estandarización.

La base tiene solo en los registros el número 1 para identificar si el campo esta registrado (la base es de servicios y cada columna con el "1" muestra si tiene el permiso de la columna mencionada), algunos campos están en *NULL* para identificar que no cuentan con permiso de del registro.

Realizaré una interfaz web que me ayude, mediante **CHECKBOX** de las columnas y así devolver los registros que tengan un aproximado según lo seleccionado en la interfaz web.

La intención de mi pregunta es para poder realizar una consulta que me devuelva varios resultados de la misma consulta parecidos o semejantes. Ayúdenme por favor.

A continuación coloco una impresión de pantalla de la base de datos:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Cada columna es un permiso, si el permiso tiene registrado un 1 es por que ese registro tiene acceso al servicio. Es decir que la consulta debe buscar que registros tienen los servicios con 1 en las columnas.

Un ejemplo es que mi base tiene estás características:

```
id nombre servicio1 servicio2 servicio3 servicio4 servicio5

1  super     1         1          1         1        1 

2  admin     null      1          null      1        1

3  admin2    null      null       1         null     null
```

En la interfaz están los servicios con un **checkbox** y dependiendo los que tú selecciones la consulta debe devolver el más parecido a los servicios que has seleccionado y algún registro extra que sea parecido.

Comment: explica a detalle por favor exactamente que resultados exsperas obtener, de ser posible agrega la estructura de tu tabla

Comment: No se entiende la pregunta. Conviene que intentes algo y plantees la pregunta a raíz de alguna dificultad en base a lo que has intentado.

Comment: @AlfredoPaz espero obtener mediante la consulta registros con los servicios solicitados en la interfaz y también obtener registros parecidos o semejantes.

Comment: @A.Cedano la consulta que quiero hacer es un select * from paloalto where abortion = 1... y así pero que la consulta me devuelva registros parecidos. No sé como hacerlo en MySQL

Comment: registros parecidos a que?

Comment: la verdad nose entiende muy bien tu pregunta, a que te refieres con registros parecidos...seria bueno que crearas tu consulta esperada... es decir que campos buscas obtener.. y mediante que filtros o condiciones...

Comment: ¿Lo que pretendes hacer es lanzar una consulta y que te devuelva todos los servicios que tiene habilitados o a los que tiene acceso ese usuario?

Comment: Que quiere decir parecido??? no sabemos que es un registro parecido.. un ejemplo???

Comment: es decir que supongamos que yo solicito en la interfaz que un registro tenga el servicio1, servicio3 y el servicio4. Que me muestre que registros tienen ese tipo de servicios. A eso me refiero a parecidos o semejantes. No sé como realizar la pregunta

Comment: explica eso con un ejemplo en la pregunta. y ademas lo que estas preguntando es un select con un where simple.. el problema son las reglas para lo que llamas parecido.. quien tiene prioridad sobre quien? cuales son las reglas de seleccion?

Comment: has la consulta de todos los campos, lo guardas en un array, recorres el array uno a uno y vas verificando cuales tienen 1 y cuales tienen null....

Comment: @jeanpitx eso es exactamente lo que quiero hacer pero como amigo?

Comment: que lenguaje utilizas? para hacer tus consultas?

Comment: MySQL y php @jeanpitx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

lo que estas buscando es un codigo de consulta a mysql en php, muy comun en la comunidad te lo pongo a continuacion para tu caso

```
 <?php
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "";
$dbname = "basedatos";

// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
}

$sql = "SELECT * FROM tutabla";
$result = $conn->query($sql);
$posicion=0;
if ($result->num_rows > 0) { //si existen datos
    // recorres fila a fila con el while y la funcion fetch_assoc
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        //con el foreach recorres todos los campos almacenados en esa fila
        foreach ($row as $valor) {
             if($valor==1)
             {echo $valor; //aqui estas recorriendo todos los valores de tu tabla y mostrandolos si son iguales a uno, otra pregunta seria si son iguales a null o algo parecido, ya depende de tu desarrollo como programador.
              }
        }
    }
} else {
    echo "0 results";
}
$conn->close();
?>
```

es la manera en que debes hacerlo, es cuestion de que lo leas, analises y lo adaptes a tus necesidades